# Why does the activity tab show congratulations for previously earned badge, when I have earned "Access to site analytics" privilege?

Tags: support, privileges, tag-badges

I have earned the "Access to site analytics" privilege today,

> [image]

After that, I visited my Activity page,

Why does it show Congratulations! for the silver badge of `mongodb` tag that I earned 7 months ago on [Dec 30 '20](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1375/mongodb?userid=8987128)?

> [image]

I recall I previously selected "Track my next privilege" in setting icon for "Access to site analytics" privilege in Next Privilege,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have less than 25K reputation, that part of the profile can be configured to either track tag badges or privileges.

Once you have more than 25K there are no more privileges available so the privilege tracking option is removed and the section can only then track tag badges.

Since the section is now tracking tag badges, it's showing you the last tag badge you earned.